# Cyber punk film (80-90's) where a girl escapes under a fence by removing a disc from her spine

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyberpunk

When she tries to escape, someone is helping her, but finally if I remember correctly she is caught. I think she was in some kind of prison city or she was a slave to the system, and that spinal disc is what keeps her tied to this place.

I saw it on Tv, 30 years ago; it was animated and I thought it was in Spanish.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you see this?  Was it live-action or animated?  What language was it in?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This could be an episode of the animated series [*"Aeon Flux"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86on_Flux), in particular episode S03E03 *"Thanatophobia"*.

The synopsis from Wikipedia says:

> [...] two Breen lovers, Onan and Sybil, seek to escape from Bregna into Monica through a gap in the frontier. The escape is almost a success, but one of the turrets shoots Sybil in the back, destroying one of her vertebrae. Now she can only stand up straight when a special ampoule is inserted, though when she takes it out she has otherwise impossible flexibility, making crossing successfully a stronger possibility.

At the end, as you remembered, the escape plan fails.

The series style and themes are peculiar, and they could be described as cyberpunk; it aired on MTV in the Nineties, which matches too.

The only element that doesn't match is that it's a series, not a movie.

Comment: Here is a [low quality youtube video of the episode](https://youtu.be/ik46G6elmnY?t=249) to check if that's what you were looking for. A word of caution: the series could be considered NSFW.

Comment: I also immediately thought of that episode.

Comment: Yes, you were right! Thanks a lot! I was maybe 6 years old when I saw it, more than 30 years ago! I have just watched it in  youtube, so many years twisting on my head and I solved it just asking in the right place. Thanks again Ifurini, you are great!